# Filtered Synchronization with SQL Azure and SQL CE3.5 using MS Sync Framework

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm busy with a project to synchronize a SQL Azure and SQL CE 3.5 database. Each client has his\her's own CE database locally. When the client synchronizes with SQL Azure, only data relevant to the specific user needs to be synchronized.
So I've created filter templates on the server for the table (only one at this point) that needs to be synchronized. I have specified all the Select, Update and Delete commands for the SyncAdapter, including the commands to retrieve the New and Max TimeStamps...

When I run the synchronization code I get the following error: "**Failed to Execute Provider Command 'SelectNewTimestampCommand'. The transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is correct and check the inner exception for any store-specific errors.**"

The Inner Exception looks like this: "
  **InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       Message=Incorrect syntax near '–'.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=15
       LineNumber=1
       Number=102
       Procedure=""
       Server=tcp:lm5a34jqb2.database.windows.net
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncScopeHandler.GetLocalTimestamp(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)
       InnerException:** 
"

The error indicates: "Incorrect syntax near '-'" but that is just the command specified to retrieve the new TimeStamp. The code that created that command looks like this: 
"SqlCommand selectNewTimestampCommand = new SqlCommand();
            string newTimestampVariable = "@" + DbSyncSession.SyncNewTimestamp;

```
        selectNewTimestampCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        selectNewTimestampCommand.Parameters.Add(newTimestampVariable, SqlDbType.Timestamp);
        selectNewTimestampCommand.Parameters[newTimestampVariable].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        selectNewTimestampCommand.CommandText = "SELECT " + newTimestampVariable + " = ((min_active_rowversion()) – 1)";

       mySyncProvider.SelectNewTimestampCommand = selectNewTimestampCommand;"
```

The only answer I seem to get on the internet, is that SP2 for SQL Server 2005 is not installed... Since I do not use SQL 2005, the solution is quite useless.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

any particular reason why you're manually setting the adapters rather than having Sync Framework provision them for you?

have a look at the sample code here: [How to: Configure and Execute Synchronization with SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928617%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)
 and here: [Extending SQL Azure data to SQL Compact using Sync Framework 2.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/13/extending-sql-azure-data-to-sql-compact-using-sync-framework-2-1.aspx)

Comment: Hi JuneT, 
Thanks for the reply... I'm quite new to the Sync Framework and according to the resources I found, if I want to create a Filtered scope, to specify only certain data to be synchronized, creating the adapters manually was the way out... Thanks for the links, I will most def read through them. I eventually overcame my problem, by creating a stored proc on the server that contains the sql statement in the commandtext property being set in my code. So instead of supplying a sql query as commandtext I supply a stored proc. And that solved the problem.
Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: good to hear you got it working. am not sure how complex the filtered scope you're creating, but the OOTB provisioning should allow you to specify which columns you want to sync and filtercolumn/filterclause should allow you to filter which rows to sync.